# How can I extract bank data and import it into Excel in OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, plaid, onlinebanking, excel-online

I'm currently manually entering data from my bank accounts into a spreadsheet in OneDrive.

I would like to be able to automate this process in some way.

The two issues I am facing in automating this are:

- How do I extract transactions from my bank account?
- How do I enter data into a spreadsheet in OneDrive?

If I had Excel installed I could probably enter the data using VBScript or VBA, but I only have the web version of Excel that comes with OneDrive.

I want to extract the transaction data direct from the bank account and not do screen scraping or manually download statements and parse these.

**NB:** If a makes a difference, the bank account is in https://www.bmo.com and one of the online accounting applications I tried seemed to be connecting with plaid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a whole lot about the OneDrive piece, but Plaid should work for pulling transactions. For inspiration, this script (https://github.com/hirefrank/plaid-txns-google-sheets) is an example of a similar app but using Google Sheets instead of OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a finance data import tool like Fintable. It automatically syncs transactions to Airtable, and from there you could export to Excel. BMO is supported, and the monthly plan is $12.